# Magento 2 : Table Rate Shipping Method Not Working

Tags: magento2, shipping, table-rates

The table rate shipping method in Magento 2.3.1 is not shown in the checkout.

It could be that I missed some configuration point, but as of my knowledge and the information in the internet this is not the case.

Upload of the csv file did work and as of the sample which I got from the export everythink should be OK.

Flate rate and free shipping is working.

Does have somebody the same problem and found a solution for it?

Comment: try matrix rate if you are still facing issue https://magecomp.com/magento-2-matrix-rates.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this issues when setting up my table rate shipping.
 It seems like this is a Magento 2 issue. You can check the issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7198

Hope that they will resolve this issue in near future.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following Sites to enable Table Rates Shipping Method

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-table-rates-shipping-method-magento-2.html

[image]